# How to bubble a child's MouseDown up to parent in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, event-bubbling

I have a WPF Window with an `<Image>` that has a `<Rectangle>` as its child FrameworkElement.  The desired behavior I would like is for Middle Mouse buttons on the rectangle to allow it to be moved around the image and and Left/Right MouseDown on the `<Rectangle>` or `<Image>` to make the rectangle decrease/increase in size.  I have the dragging of the child `<Rectangle>` around the `<Image>` working, as well as having the Left/Right clicks handled by the Rectangle.  How can I have the Left/Right MouseDown be handled by the `<Image>` so I don't have to duplicate the code  for changing the size of the rectangle in the child and parent?

Answer (score 1):

Here you can do similar below:

```
<Grid Background="Transparent" StackPanel.MouseDown="StackPanel_MouseDown">
    <StackPanel Margin="70" Background="DarkGray" MouseDown="StackPanel_MouseDown">
        <TextBlock x:Name="XTextBlock"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void StackPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender.GetType().Name.Equals("StackPanel"))
        {
            XTextBlock.Text = "I am direct raised from StackPanel.";
        }
        else //sender.GetType().Name.Equals("Grid")
        {
            XTextBlock.Text += "I am bubble raised from Grid.";
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will address your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the routed event tunneling behavior by using `PreviewMouseDown` as below:

```
<Grid Background="Transparent" PreviewMouseDown="Grid_PreviewMouseDown">
    <StackPanel Margin="70" Background="DarkGray" Grid.PreviewMouseDown="Grid_PreviewMouseDown">
        <TextBlock x:Name="XTextBlock"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Grid_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender.GetType().Name.Equals("StackPanel"))
        {
            XTextBlock.Text += ", I am tunneled raised from StackPanel.";
        }
        else //sender.GetType().Name.Equals("Grid")
        {
            XTextBlock.Text = "I am direct raised from Grid.";
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will helps. Keep coding :)

Comment: One thing which is slightly different in my case is that I need to selectively handle MouseDown in the child depending on which Mouse button was pressed. Is there a way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

To check which button was pressed you can use the MouseButtonEventArgs. 
For example

```
if(e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Thumb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.thumb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control. You can easily set up a Grid of 9 thumbs like that :

```
+--+-----------+--+
|  |           |  |
+--+-----------+--+    
|  |           |  |
|  |           |  |
|  |           |  |
|  |           |  |
|  |           |  |
+--+-----------+--+    
|  |           |  |
+--+-----------+--+
```

Assign proper cursors to each thumb, and handle the thumbs' drag events according to their positions. It's way more robust than handling to mouse down/up/move events yourself.